# Javascript events don't work ofter ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a page that uses JS to bind some event handlers, and later, to make an AJAX call. Everything works fine until the AJAX runs, but after that, all my event handlers stop working. Does anyone know why this would happen?

I haven't posted my AJAX code because it's past the maximum length, and I'm not sure which parts of it are relevant.

```
<div class="div_mem"> eee </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".div_mem")
    .mouseover(function () {
      $(this).css({ "background-color": "#101010" });
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
      $(this).css({ "background-color": "" });
    });
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: Where's the ajax call?

Comment: Pleas add the code relevant to this question, like the ajax call code.

Comment: This portion of code works for me.

Comment: the web didnt let me load the ajax code. its tell me that the code is the most of the post

Comment: looks like an issue of event delegation.. probably use (document).on('event','selector', function()) .. might fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably replacing the `.div_mem` element during the AJAX call, right? Even if you replace it with another `.div_mem` element, the event handlers are still bound to the old object. You need to make sure they use the *current* result of `$(".div_mem")`.

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".div_mem", function () {
  $(this).css({ "background-color": "#101010" });
})
.on("mouseout", ".div_mem", function () {
  $(this).css({ "background-color": "" });
});
```